# Finding best approximation

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation

I was practicing my best approximation when I found this question:

Find the best approximation of $f$ in $G$, $f \in G$

$H:L^{2}[0,1]$ ; $ G = \{g \in H | \int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx = 0 \} $ ; $ f(x) = e^{x}$

I am not sure how to solve this problem. I know that for $g$ to be the best approximation of $f$ it has to satisfy the condition that $(f-g) \perp G$. But I am unable to apply it in this case.
I also know that the approximation will exist since $G$ is closed.

Comment: Can you find a nonzero element $h \in G^{\perp}$? Can you see that $G^{\perp} = \operatorname{span} \{h\}$ then?

Comment: @DanielFischer any constant function will belong to $ G^{\perp}$. But I cannot see how $G^{\perp}$  = $span\{h\}$. If $G^{\perp}$  = $span\{h\}$ is true then I would have $ f - g = constant$ and I can find g from it. But how do i show that $G^{\perp}$  = $span\{h\}$

Comment: @modesty Do you know the concept of the codimension?

Comment: Note that $L^2[0,1] \subset L^1[0,1]$. Hence $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ is well-defined for every $f\in H$. Now let $c(x) = 1$, and write $$f = \biggl(\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx)\biggr)\cdot c + \Biggl( f - \biggl(\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\biggr)\cdot c\Biggr).$$

Comment: @Christian no I am not familiar with the concept of codimension

Comment: @DanielFischer would you please explain a bit more. I am unable to connect what you wrote with my doubt of how to show $ G^{\perp} = span\{h\}$